# Finding pattern in binary file?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have this two functions:

```
def make_regex_from_hex_sign(hex_sign):
    regex_hex_sign = re.compile(hex_sign.decode('hex'))
    return regex_hex_sign

def find_regex_pattern_and_return_its_offset(regex_pattern, bytes_array):
    if found_regex_pattern in regex_pattern.finditer(bytes_array):
        return found_regex_pattern.start()
    else:
        return 0
```

and i'm using them like this:

```
pattern = make_regex_from_hex_sign("634351535F")
file = open('somefile.bin', 'rb')
allbytes = file.read()
offset = find_regex_pattern_and_return_its_offset(pattern, allbytes)
```

Python throws: `NameError: global name 'found_regex_pattern' is not defined`

If i replace `if` with `for` in `if found_regex_pattern in regex_pattern.finditer(bytes_array)` it works, but then i need to `break` at the end to stop it from searching past first found pattern iteration. Is there more elegant way to solve this without using `for` and `break`?

Comment: This is a scoping issue entirely unrelated to what you're trying to do. Your indentation is wonky so that needs fixing before this can be definitively answered

Comment: Sorry, just noticed it. Fixed.

Comment: Using the `for` loop will iterate over `regex_pattern.finditer(bytes_array)` with a loop variable called `found_regex_pattern`. Using `if` will try to resolve finding `found_regex_pattern` within `regex_pattern.finditer(bytes_array)`. As mentioned above, this will fail if there is no variable `found_regex_pattern` in scope. But these are two completely different tasks. You should figure out what you're trying to do and use the right construct for it.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Actually i want the same behavior as using `for`, but without it because i only need the first found pattern iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define found_regex_pattern.
When you do the change from if to for it works because its a valid syntax and that means that found_regex_pattern  acts as an entry of the regex_pattern.finditer(bytes_array) iterable.